# How to use Select Exists in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the equivalent of the below **`SQL Query`** in **`Oracle`**?

```
SELECT CAST(
   CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM theTable where theColumn like 'theValue%') THEN 1 
   ELSE 0 
   END 
AS BIT)
```

I just want an oracle query where exists is used and it returns 0 or 1 like above.

Comment: What is the requirement, it will be great if you could share the table structure and the kind of output you require, some sample output will be appreciated

Comment: don't worry about the table structure. I just want an oracle query where exists is used and it returns 0 or 1.

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to use both , the requirement may be serverd by one only , it will better make sense if you could share the requirement or the form in which you want to see data

Answer (score 15):

The equivalent would be:

```
select count(*) 
from dual 
where exists (SELECT * FROM theTable where theColumn like 'theValue%')
```

Comment: I've been told to use count(1) and exists (select 1 ...) to improve performance, but I never checked if there's any actual imrpovement. Sounds logical, though.

Comment: This gives an error if the condition isn't met, instead of returning a 0, if you use a table that doesn't exist.

Comment: @vapcguy The existence of a table is another type of problem.

Comment: There is no difference between (*) and (1)

Comment: This one is not equivalent to the OP desired result because OP is looking for a result whether or not it exists. 1 or 0. I believe ypercube's answer is correct, I'll be trying it myself now.

Answer (score 15):

This would show the same output. Just removed the `CAST` and added a `FROM dual` as Oracle doesn't allow queries with `SELECT` and without `FROM`:

```
SELECT 
   CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM theTable where theColumn like 'theValue%') 
     THEN 1 
     ELSE 0 
   END 
FROM dual ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f0766/2)**

Answer (score 7):

You could write it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM theTable WHERE theColumn LIKE 'theValue%' AND ROWNUM = 1
```

This will return `0-1` and the optimizer gets that the query is to be optimized for first-row access.

Comment: I guess, this won't work in `if` condition. Like `if(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM theTable WHERE theColumn LIKE 'theValue%' AND ROWNUM = 1)>0`.

Comment: @techdo: this won't work in PLSQL since you can't use `SELECT` with `IF` in PL. However, this will work everywhere a `SELECT` is permitted, notably in the `SELECT` clause or inside a `CASE` statement (`CASE WHEN (SELECT count(*) ...) > 0 THEN ... ELSE ... END`).

Comment: Okay... Yeah. Thank you... Just wanted to confirm that.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat: you *can* use an `IF` in **PL/SQL**, but not in (Oracle's) SQL. PL/SQL in Oracle is only applicable in stored procedures. Everything else is "just" SQL.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use MAX with CASE:

```
SELECT MAX(
   CASE 
     WHEN theColumn like 'theValue%' THEN 1 
   ELSE 
     0 
   END)  
AS BIT
FROM theTable
```

Answer (score -1):

### You can use one of the following queries: (the first ones is more performant)

```
SELECT H.TABLE_ID, H.OTHER_FIELD, 
(SELECT 'YES' FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (SELECT  'X' FROM TABLE_DETAIL DT
WHERE DT.TABLE_ID = H.TABLE_ID) ) WITH_DETAIL FROM TABLE_HEADER H;
```

---

```
SELECT H.TABLE_ID, H.OTHER_FIELD, 
CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT * FROM IMTS.DETAIL_TABLE DT WHERE DT.TABLE_ID=H.TABLE_ID)  
THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END WITH_DETAIL FROM HEADER_TABLE H;
```

```
SELECT H.TABLE_ID, H.OTHER_FIELD, NVL2(DT.SOME_NOTNULL_FIELD, 'YES','NO') WITH_DETAIL
FROM TABLE_HEADER H
LEFT JOIN TABLE_DETAIL DT ON DT.TABLE_ID=H.TABLE_ID AND ROWNUM<2;
```